# How to i can refresh value in combobox when added , deleted data in C# - winform?

Tags: c#, combobox, refresh

I added MaMon value = 11, it is displayed by datagridview but MaMon combobox is not
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Ali.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

i creat void LoadData and call it whenever creat, update, view, del

```
     void LoadData() {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source = D:\Project\DataKTHT.mdb";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from table", conn);
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(tb);
        dataGridView_MonHoc.DataSource = tb;
        cboMaMon.DataSource = tb;
        cboMaMon.DisplayMember = "TenMon";
        cboMaMon.ValueMember = "MaMon";
     }
```